# Checking file names inside a directory with Regular Expressions

Tags: bash, regex

I have a list of files inside a directory and I want to make a bash script which uses a regular expression to check if every file name inside it has this syntax:

```
xxxx_xxxx_xx_xx
```

Where x are numbers.

Edit: I only need  with the regex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
for f in *
do
  [[ $f =~ [0-9]{4}_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2} ]] || 
    echo "File $f does not match"
done
```

The regular expression checks for any digit (`[0-9]`). The numbers in curly braces are the number of repetitions so `[0-9]{4}` will match any 4 digits.

I would recommend you don't use bash for this but find instead. It will probably be faster,  and it is certainly more portable (not all shells can deal with regular expressions):

```
find -regextype posix-egrep -not -regex '\./[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}'
```

Comment: I can’t construct a scenario that causes your `find` command to break, but I still believe (on general principles) that the regex should probably be quoted, for safety.

Comment: @Scott I tend to agree with such precautionary quoting but I don't know of any shell that would choke on that. Still, as you said, better safe than sorry. Quotes added.

Comment: OK, I had my _n+1_ th injection of caffeine, and I figured it out. It’s not an issue of ***the shell choking***, _per se_. If there is a file in the current directory with a name like `5{4}_3{4}_0{2}_9{2}` (and you don’t have shell globbing turned off), then `\./[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}` (your regex) will expand to `./5{4}_3{4}_0{2}_9{2}`, and your `find` will match only `./5555_3333_00_99` (if it exists). … … (BTW, 5309 is the last four digits of Jenny’s phone number.)

Comment: @Scott ah, yes, well found! Who's Jenny? Or should I not ask?

Comment: Seriously? Oh, I see; you don’t live in a primarily English-speaking country. [Here you go.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/867-5309/Jenny)

Comment: @Scott ah, huh, no I'd never heard of that, no. Mind you, I was two in 1982 so I might not have heard of it even if I'd grown up in the English speaking world :).

Answer (score 1):

It’s clunky, but this should be very portable:

```
#!/bin/sh
for x in *
do
    case "$x" in
        [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9])
            echo "$x matches"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "$x  doesn’t match"
    esac
done
#                       And, to be annoyingly complete,
for x in .*
do
    echo "$x  doesn’t match"
done
```

Comment: Same regex i used, btw i think that the solution provided by @terdon is cleaner. Thanks anyway!